# Change text in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am new with ASP.NET. This is my code:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button Text="Change" runat="server" ID="BtnChangeText" OnClick="BtnChangeText_OnClick"/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblTest" Text="Change me!"></asp:Label>        
        </ContentTemplate>          
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my server code:

```
    protected void BtnChangeText_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblTest.Text = "Hello World!";
    }
```

Why does it not work?. How can I do for this work?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after your `</ContentTemplate>`

```
<Triggers>         
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Change" EventName="Click" /> 
</Triggers>
```

Comment: As both controls are inside updatepanel, His code should work. Still i have no idea about trigger but i am using ajax and its working. Whats Difference then?

Comment: @ALOK that is right, the code should have worked. Triggers help when using multiple update panels or cause update panel to refresh on external event. Check this out: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have set the **updateMode property** to `Conditional` so it will the updatePanel won't be refreshed automatically (as this was default)!!

Simpel solution set it back to `Always`

**MSDN UpdateMode**

*Always*
The content of the UpdatePanel control is updated for all postbacks that originate from the page. This includes asynchronous postbacks.

*Conditional*
The content of the UpdatePanel control is updated under the following conditions:

- If the Update method of the UpdatePanel control is called explicitly.
- If a control is defined as a trigger by using the Triggers property of the UpdatePanel control and causes a postback. In this scenario, the control is an explicit trigger for updating the panel content. The trigger control can be either inside or outside the UpdatePanel control that defines the trigger.
- If the ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true and a child control of the UpdatePanel control causes a postback. In this scenario, child controls of the UpdatePanel control are implicit triggers for updating the panel. Child controls of nested UpdatePanel controls do not cause the outer UpdatePanel control to be updated unless they are explicitly defined as triggers.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155262(v=vs.110).aspx) for further details!

Comment: This may be wrong on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 with .NET 4.0 and Mono version 4.4.0. Thank you.